# write isito yaml(kind Gateway , kind VirtualService) file for kubernates in java

Tags: java, kubernetes, yaml, istio, fabric8

i want to write isito yaml (kind Gateway , kind VirtualService) file for kubernates in java
[this](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/helloworld/helloworld-gateway.yaml) is the sample yaml file i am referring

so i want to use only kubernates/isito client for generating the yaml content

i have tried fabic8, but no luck.

Comment: What you mean by `write istio yaml for kubernetes in java`? You want to use [kubernetes java library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) to create these 2 yamls with java?

Comment: Please check out Fabric8, it has extensions for Knative, Tekton and Istio too(the snowdrop repository is also an extension of main Fabric8 client)

Answer (score 2):

finally, after struggle found this https://github.com/snowdrop/istio-java-api/blob/master/istio-client/src/test/java/me/snowdrop/istio/client/it/GatewayIT.java and resolved